# flatMap() vs subscribe() in Spring webflux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am a newbie to Spring WebFlux and trying to convert my spring MVC application to webflux. I return a Mono mono from my service :

```
    List<Store> stores = new ArrayList();
```

When I do:

```
    mono.subscribe(stores::addAll);
    dataexchange.put("stores", stores);
    return Mono.just(dataexchange);
```

Then stores is populated as empty list in response. However, I can verify that subscribe() is working after returning response.

When I do :

```
    return mono.flatmap( (response) -> {
        dataexchange.put("stores", response));
        return Mono.just(dataexchange);
    });
```

Then stores is populated in the response.

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between the two? Is flatMap blocking?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```java
mono.subscribe(stores::addAll);
```

is asynchronous. That means, you tell the mono that it can now **start** evaluating.

What you do is continue processing `stores` right away - with a huge chance that the `Mono` hasn't evaluated yet.

So, how can you fix this?

You can **block** until the `Mono` has completed:

```
mono.doOnNext(stores::addAll).block()
```

Of course, this defeats the purpose of reactive programming. You are blocking the main thread until an action completes, which can be achieved without Reactor in a much simpler fashion.

---

The right way is to change the rest of your code to be reactive too, from head to toe. This is similar to your second example, where your call to `dataexchange` is part of the `Mono`, thus being evaluated asynchronously, too.

The important lesson to be learned is that operations like `map` or `flatMap` are not operating on the result of the `Mono`, but create a new `Mono` that adds another transformation to the execution of the original `Mono`. As long as the `Mono` doesn't evaluate, the `flatMap` or `map` operations are not actually doing anything.

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: So, that means that flaptmap isn't blocking? Also, I have read in a number of articles that "Nothing happens until you subscribe" , i.e. no data flow is available until you subscribe. Then how does flatmap work without subscribe() ?

Comment: @XYZ I can't tell from your example where you return your `Mono` to, but it absolutely shouldn't.

Comment: I am returning this mono directly from controller. Can you please answer why flatmap() works without subscribe()?

Comment: @XYZ it doesn't. Try it in a sandbox environment (without any controllers and other side effects). I think Spring handles the `Mono` when you return it by subscribing to it.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but doing a search in documentation of mongoDB using reactive driver. There are an example using CountDownLatch. After use the CountDownLatch I can see all steps from log of Webflux. Before I can`t